Gaps in print bed
I get these weird gaps inside my model, I know there are some other issues with this print.

I would say this is the one that troubles me the most; I will also say that I have thin walls in this model and the walls are sometimes printed with gaps.
I have made available the stl, the G-code, and the printer settings via a Google Drive link.

Hi Eden, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE. Please do not link to external images, SE has its own image servers that are retained as long as this site exists. Use the "insert image button" when uploading images, they will be shown inline, not as a link.

okay very sorry, it was a mistake.. i am used to this from other forums when the image is too big

@0scar - the new link/domain for stack exchange images is now i.sstatic.net. I got caught out by this yesterday..! :-) See Stack Exchange’s image hosting arrangement with Imgur is ending - advance notice. It kicked in April 3, but I only noticed it yesterday.

@EdenDolev - Hi and welcome to SE.3DP! Don't worry, you did nothing wrong at all. The domain has changed from imgur and we weren't made aware, hence our confusion.  :-)

thank you all for the comments and warm welcome! I will update that increasing the parameters: skin overlap percentage and infill overlap percentage helped in a smaller model, I will let him finish and then try on the model on this topic.

So the print for the smaller model came out quite well. I do have a few issues still, as can be seen in the pictures i will add. (hopefully correctly this time)  First there is a weird gap inside the walls, thought about turning down the line width but that has an hardware limit of the nozzle and i don't want to hurt the achievement of a full print. Second there is still a small gap, increased by another 5 precent and hope it will be enough. Gapped Wall. Gap in base (google search revealed there is no way to add images to comment)

It looks like your printer has positioning issues. You definitely need to check the mechanical aspects of the printer, e.g belts properly tensioned? What printer is it?

@oscar it is creailty ender 3 v2 neo, i tried to check my belts, but didn't find a good guide for it

Hi still having issues with this
